# What do if new employer wants the relieving letter at the time of joining, but previous employer will provide it later?

Tags: job-change, india, relieving-letter

My previous employer did not provide me the relieving letter on the last working day. The HR says they will give me the relieving letter and experience letter after 45 days.

My new employer says they require the original relieving letter at the time of joining.

How should I handle this situation?

Comment: 'get nothing in written in last working day' seems unclear. Can you explain your situation more clearly and what it is that you were expecting to get in writing?

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: "[When someone completes a notice period and still doesn't get a relieving letter (India), how to tackle this?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13642/when-someone-completes-a-notice-period-and-still-doesnt-get-a-relieving-letter)" and " [How can I explain to potential employers that I am unable to provide a relieving letter?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21372/how-can-i-explain-to-potential-employers-that-i-am-unable-to-provide-a-relieving)"

Comment: See also: "[What is a relieving letter? What are the consequences of not having one?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-is-a-relieving-letter-what-are-the-consequences-of-not-having-one)"

Answer (score 0):

Explain the situation to the new employer. The new employer would most likely allow you to submit the relieving letter later since it is usually impractical to provide it on the joining day.

*Disclosure: Rest of this answer is self plagiarised from [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/113024/3192).*

The relieving letter can be, and usually is, submitted after coming on board. It is usually impractical to submit the relieving letter on or before the joining day because:

- People usually join the new job within a few days of ending the previous job. AND
- The previous employer provides the relieving letter along with the so-called "full and final settlement", which takes a couple of weeks.

As a result, the new employer typically provides the employee up to a couple of months after joining to submit the relieving letter.